Colored chapters in memoir cause page breaks before lists
Imagine that I try to make my chapter titles red in memoir. Then by inserting appropriate skips, I can get a page break between the heading and a list environment coming after (see example below). By commenting out the line \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{red}} and uncommenting the previous line, the problem vanishes.
Also, for some reason that I don’t quite understand, this will cause Hi to appear on the second page.
Inspired by my other question here, I tried inserting \leavevmode and \mbox{}, but that didn’t change anything.
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}


%\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries} % no issue
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{red}} % issue


\begin{document}


Hi

\vspace*{49em}

\chapter*{Hello}

\begin{itemize}
    \item World
\end{itemize}

\end{document}



My quess is the whatsit that \color sets. But remember that you can end \chaptitlefont with a macro taking one arg, fx \textcolor{red}

@daleif I tried replacing \color{red} by \textcolor{red} in the above example. Now only the H is red.

My bad, forgot to add this \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont {#1}}, I thought that was the default for chapter as well. There might be a reason why it is not, do not remember. The default us just #1 without the braces.

@daleif I forgot to say that this solved the problem, but it did. Go ahead and add an answer if you want points for it.
